# Grails Release plugin maven-deploy command fails 401 error with Sonatype Nexus

Tags: maven, grails, nexus

- OS: Windows7
- Grails: 2.4.3
- Sonatype Nexus: 2.9.2-01
- Maven: 3,2,3

---

### This question was solved!

A cause is typo.

In BuildConfig.groovy

before:

```
grails.project.repos.myRepo.url = "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
grails.project.repos.myRepo.type = "maven"
grails.project.repos.myRepo.username = "deployment"
grails.project.repos.myRepo.password = "deployment123"
```

after:

```
grails.project.repos.snapshots.url = "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
grails.project.repos.snapshots.type = "maven"
grails.project.repos.snapshots.username = "deployment"
grails.project.repos.snapshots.password = "deployment123"
```

I had forgotten change repositoryID.

If forget any one of these, get back 401.

Thanks a lot!

---

I decide host my developing plugin on Sonatype Nexus as local Maven repository to check the plugin behaviour when actually installed in standalone Glails app.

At first, I installed Maven and Sonatype Nexus.

### Maven

Download zip and extract it to just below C drive.

```
C:\apache-maven-3.2.3
```

Next, I created two system properties and concat M2 to Path.

```
M2_HOME
C:\apache-maven-3.2.3

M2
%M2ZHOME%\bin

Path tail
~~~~~~~~%M2%;
```

### Sonatype Nexus

Download zip and extract it to just below C drive.

```
C:\nexus-2.9.2-01-bundle
```

---

Then Execute install and start command, nexus webapp was started successfully.

---

Next, I wrote BuildConfig.groovy that Release plugin configuration.

```
grails.project.repos.snapshots.url = "http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"
grails.project.repos.myRepo.type = "maven"
grails.project.repos.myRepo.username = "deployment"
grails.project.repos.myRepo.password = "deployment123"
grails.project.repos.default = "snapshots"
```

"snapshots" is repository that available from the beginning Sonatype Nexus.

---

Finally, I execute maven-deploy command and got a error message below.

```
| Error Error deploying artifact: Error deploying artifact 'org.grails.plugins:myplugin:zip': Error deploying artifact: Failed to transfer file: http://loca
lhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/org/grails/plugins/myplugin/
0.1/myplugin-0.1.zip. Return code is: 401
| Error Have you specified a configured repository to deploy to (--repository ar
gument) or specified distributionManagement in your POM?
```

What am I wrong?

Comment: At a glance, it's because "myRepo" must be changed to "snapshots"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling for `Sonatype Nexus 401` gives you the answer: http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/11/what-to-do-when-nexus-returns-401/

Comment: Let me confirm. Thank you very much!